# R -- Add value for any repeating values within a group_by

Tags: r

I'm attempting to identify repeated values within a group_by in a data frame, and have those repeated values be mutated onto a new column. The example table looks like this:

| id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 1 | mike |
| 2 | jess |
| 2 | aron |
| 2 | jess |
| 3 | carl |
| 3 | carl |
| 3 | john |

I would like the output to be:

| id | Value | dupes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john |  |
| 1 | mike |  |
| 2 | jess | jess |
| 2 | aron |  |
| 2 | jess | jess |
| 3 | carl | carl |
| 3 | carl | carl |
| 3 | john |  |

I've used this before `df_new <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(dupes = ifelse(n_distinct(Value)>1 ,Value,""))`

But unsure how to modify this to give the desired output, perhaps using the `any()` along with a `case_when()` function?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the **ifelse** statement

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id, Value) %>%
  mutate(dupes = ifelse(n() > 1 , Value, '')) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do a group by 'Value' as well, then create the logic with `n()` - number of rows i.e. if it is greater than 1, then return the 'Value' or else blank (`""`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id, Value) %>%
   mutate(dupes = case_when(n() > 1 ~ Value, TRUE ~ '')) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#     id Value dupes 
#  <int> <chr> <chr> 
#1     1 john  ""    
#2     1 mike  ""    
#3     2 jess  "jess"
#4     2 aron  ""    
#5     2 jess  "jess"
#6     3 carl  "carl"
#7     3 carl  "carl"
#8     3 john  ""
```

---

Or in `base R`, this can be done with `duplicated`

```
df1$dupes <- df1$Value
df1$dupes[!(duplicated(df1[c('id', 'Value')])|
     duplicated(df1[c('id', 'Value')], fromLast = TRUE))] <- ""
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Value = c("john", 
"mike", "jess", "aron", "jess", "carl", "carl", "john")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: This is perfect! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A solution with with `length()` function instead of `n()`. The logic and data is from akrun (many thanks)!

```
  library(dplyr)
  df1 %>% 
    group_by(id, Value) %>%
    mutate(dupes = ifelse(length(Value) > 1 , Value, '')) %>%
    ungroup
```

Output:

```
     id Value dupes 
  <int> <chr> <chr> 
1     1 john  ""    
2     1 mike  ""    
3     2 jess  "jess"
4     2 aron  ""    
5     2 jess  "jess"
6     3 carl  "carl"
7     3 carl  "carl"
8     3 john  ""
```